# Invoking a webserice using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, visual-studio-2012

Trying to invoke this web service using AJAX...

The web service is as follows

```
 public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public String countryCode(String input)
    {



            StringBuilder strings = new StringBuilder("", 10000);
            String text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("countryCodes.txt"));
            String[] countries = Regex.Split(text, "#");

            var valids = new List<String>();
            foreach (String c in countries)
            {
                if (c.ToUpper().StartsWith(input.ToUpper()) || c.ToLower().StartsWith(input.ToLower()))
                {
                    if (input == "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    valids.Add(c);
                }
            }
            return (valids.Any()) ? String.Join(" ", valids) : "No results found for your input!";

        }


    }
```

I have set up an empty web form and called the service reference in the script manager like so

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And I have my javascript as follows below

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    var a = wRequest.set_userContext("user's context");
    var onClick = function () {
        CountryCodes.WebService1.countryCode($get("TextBox1"), onSucess, onFailed);
    }
    var onSuccess = function (result) {
       $get("Label3").innerHTML = result;
   }
   var onFailed = function (result) {
       $get("Label3").innerHTML = "No results found for your input!";
   }
</script>
```

Now my understanding is that when the button is pressed it will take the input of `TextBox1's` value and use it as the argument for my `WebService.countryCode` method and therefore if it succeeds it will set `label 3` to the result of the method and if it doesn't succeed it will set `label 3` to the string provided...

This however does not happen.... Infact nothing happens when I click my button, for clarity, here is my button declaration...

```
<input type="button" value="Find Country Codes " onclick ="onClick()" />
```

This button is in the same place the automated textbox1 and label code is generated.

So my question is, what have I done wrong and how can it be fixed?

Any clarifications needed just post below thank you.

Regards

EDIT : yes I have commented out this line in the web service

```
"[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate your web service class with `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`, like this:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

This allows your web service to be called by your JavaScript.

Also, change your call to the web service to remove the `CountryCodes` prefix, like this:

```
var onClick = function () {
    WebService1.countryCode($get("TextBox1"), onSucess, onFailed);
}
```

Comment: Cheers Karl, big help

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Feel free to up-vote the question as well. :-)